# why won't the arrow function work here in javaScript when trying to get an onclick event

Tags: javascript

Why does the arrow function not work when defining a function in javascript?

This works, but the arrow function doesn't for some reason.

```
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML="<img src='open.jpg' height='200px'/>"; 
}
```

This is the example that does not work:

```
let changeImage = () => {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML="<img src='open.jpg' height='200px'/>";
}
```

file.js

```
let clickOpt =
document.getElementById('header');

clickOpt.onclick= changeImage;

 let changeImage = () => {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML="<img src='open.jpg' height='200px'/>";
}
```

Comment: are you missing a curly brace on the end?

Comment: [Help Center -> How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (preferable as snippet -> `<>` / `Ctrl+M`) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: I have it in the visual studio Will, I forgot to put it in here but thanks

Comment: Maybe your browser doesn't support arrow functions

Comment: Can you please specify more details on the error?

Comment: I'm using chrome Yousername

Comment: Note that you've just said that it "does not work".  What exactly does that mean? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: I click on  the text in the browser and it goes to the linked image, but with arrow function it don't work nothing happens

Comment: Errors reported in the browser console? How exactly are you binding the function as an event handler? Overall you really haven't provided enough information for anybody to help.

Comment: This will throw a `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'changeImage' before initialization`

Comment: thanks Andreas! it worked when I  put the changeImage after! but why is it that when I used the function syntax without the arrow function the order didn't matter?

Comment: Read the answer from Pointy for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

`function` declarations are *hoisted* to the top of the enclosing scope; `let` declarations are not (well not completely).  You'll see an error in your browser console that will go away if you do the `onclick` assignment *after* the `let` declaration.

```
let changeImage = () => {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML="<img src='open.jpg' height='200px'/>";
}

clickOpt.onclick= changeImage;
```

By contrast, a `function` declaration is treated as if it actually appeared at the very start of its containing function or `<script>` body.

Note that there's no really good reason to use a `=>` function in this case.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I need to recap on the whole const and let declarations phenomenon, I  probably skimmed through it.